# jQuery access variable in html method

Tags: jquery, variables

This is my code (it's just this, nothing more)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".system").click(function() {
            var sid = this.id;
            alert(sid); // Outputs correct id
            $("#graph").html('<img src="graph.php?system=' + sid + '" />'); // sid seems to be null (call looks like "http://host/grap.php?system=")
        })
    })
```

Obviously, alerting `sid` works, while using `sid` in the html method of the selector doesn't. I've also tried writing the value into a form input and then reading it from there, but this doesn't work either.

I think, the html method doesn't support another calls or variable accessing. What would be a workaround to this?

Comment: If it's only this code, then please add `var` to `sid`.

Comment: @pimvdb I have already tried that, didn't help either :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**: the question has now been edited, so this is no longer noticeable in the example code in the question.

---

You are closing the `src` attribute value early. Change it to this:

```
$("#graph").html('<img src="graph.php?system=' + sid + '" />');
                                          //^Removed " here
```

What you currently have will result in markup like this:

```
<img src="graph.php?system="something" />
```

You can see from that that the `src` attribute value is only *graph.php?system=*, which is exactly what you say you are noticing.

By changing the aforementioned line, you will get markup like this:

```
<img src="graph.php?system=something" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but as stated in the code comment, the request made doesn't even contain the sid variable, it's just null.

Comment: @Ahatius - This is the reason the request does not contain it!

Comment: @Ahatius It's not null, but `<img src="graph.php?system="something" />` is invalid to the browser, so it's converted to whatever makes sense to it, which is just `<img src="graph.php?system=" />`

Comment: @Ahatius - Well what happens now then?

Comment: Ok, I tried again, it really was the wrong quotes. Thanks alot :)